# function Base.+ must be explicitly imported to be extended

Tags: julia, ijulia-notebook

i'm pretty new to julia forgive me if my question is dumb,

for exmaple i defined a type like this:

```
type Vector2D
    x::Float64
    y::Float64
end
```

and 2 object w and v:

```
v = Vector2D(3, 4)
w = Vector2D(5, 6)
```

if i add them up it will raise this err : `MethodError: no method matching +(::Vector2D, ::Vector2D)` it's ok , but when i want to define a method for
summing theses object

```
+(a::Vector2D, b::Vector2D) = Vector2D(a.x+b.x, a.y+b.y)
```

it raise this error :

```
error in method definition: function Base.+ must be explicitly imported to be extended
```

julia version 0.5

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As the error message says, you must tell Julia that you want to extend the `+` function from Base (the standard library):

```
import Base: +, -

+(a::Vector2D, b::Vector2D) = Vector2D(a.x + b.x, a.y + b.y)
-(a::Vector2D, b::Vector2D) = Vector2D(a.x - b.x, a.y - b.y)
```

Comment: Or just `Base.+(a::Vector2D, b::Vector2D) = Vector2D(a.x + b.x, a.y + b.y)`

Comment: Note that in Julia 0.6, this becomes `Base.:+`.

Comment: @DavidP.Sanders what's the reasoning behind that? (or do you have a link to a discussion about the relevant change?)

Comment: I think it's due to the new broadcasting functionality with `.`; see e.g. http://julialang.org/blog/2017/01/moredots